# Json Ajax Response from Django Application

Tags: javascript, django, django-views

I have a Django app that the views.py sends a json data to a javascript function on my html. The problem is that I can not access the elements of the data.

I tryied to use JsonParse but not sucess, for instance when I do

```
var other = JSON.parse(data_doc_pers['data_doc_pers']);
document.getElementById("text_conf4").innerHTML = other['doc_nome'];
```

I receive the following response: [object Object]

what I am doing wrong???

Here is my code

Views.py

```
...
json_string = json.dumps({'type_numeric':type_numeric,'type_prop':type_prop,'name':name,'Vinculo':Vinculo,'doc_nome':doc_nome})
return JsonResponse({'data_doc_pers':json_string})
```

HTML

```
$.get('{% url "page" %}',{'var':var}, function (data_doc_pers) {
   var other = JSON.parse(data_doc_pers['data_doc_pers']);
   document.getElementById("text_conf4").innerHTML = other['doc_nome'];
});
```

Comment: You're encoding twice. Don't do that; there is no need to call json.dumps before passing the data to JsonResponse. However, in order for us to really help you, you need to show what `doc_nome` is and where it is coming from.

Comment: Hi Daniel.. here is a example of what I am reciving in my request above: {"data_doc_pers": {"type_prop": "PERSON, "doc_nome": {"Nome": "JON", "SALES": "200"}, "Vinculo": "EMPLOYEE", "type_numeric": "1", "name": "JOHN MARTIR"}}

Comment: Ok, so what do you want the output to, be?

Comment: In my javascript when I do other['doc_nome'] I receive the output  [object Object].. How Can I have the output {"Nome": "JON", "SALES": "200"]??or just 200?

Comment: If you want 200, you should do `other["doc_nome"]["SALES"]`.

Comment: Do you have an idea why I am receiving [object Object] instead of the number?any guess?

Comment: The error I was doing in javscript was to usevar other = JSON.parse(data_doc_pers['data_doc_pers']); the correct should be only (data_doc_pers['data_doc_pers']. If you want answer I will mark your repply as correct.. thanks for the help

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Problem solvend!

The error I was doing in javscript was to use var other = JSON.parse(data_doc_pers['data_doc_pers']); the correct should be only (data_doc_pers['data_doc_pers'].